# How can I process a form that is common for multiple views and controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a site where most pages have a common form displayed. The form code is located in a separate file and loaded in each view like so:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/quote'); ?>
```

I did this so that I don't have to duplicate the code in every controller and view. The form data will be used to create an email. The form is displayed properly but I can't figure out how to process the input data. Since there are multiple controllers involved do I need to create a separate controller to process the data? What is the best way to handle this type of situation?

Comment: leave `action` empty in your form and it'll be submitted to current controller and create separate method to process your form which will be called from your controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use my controller which will extend ci_controller. after that every controller will extend my_controller. In my_controller create the methods that are shared among all the other controlelrs. This way you dont have to write them. They will be available. Similarly, on every controller you can submit the form with writing ectra code just handle the url i mean from which controller you are coming. for this  purpose use current_url() method. this will help.

Comment: I am familiar with the MY_Controller base class extension, but if the functions are inside MY_Controller, how will the OP post data to them? The functions must be public facing; (correct me if I'm wrong) the functions belonging to parent classes are not.

Comment: you can access my_controller functions in the child class simply call you child class and my_controlelr method. This is it

Comment: Thanks to all who offered ideas. Using the MY_controller and passing the controller name as a variable to the view did the trick. I appreciate all of the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Either what Raheel said (common controller which has a function which handles the form submission), or create a library which gets included when you need to do the processing, and you can call the library method.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a variable from each controller to identify the controller that is currently in use. You can use this to change your forms' `action` attribute, so it points to the correct controller.

Additionally, you can also use that variable to create a hidden field in the form, so, by checking for that variable in your `$_POST` you'd be able to know which form is submitted.

Comment: Passing a variable is a great idea. Thanks for the tip.